# Are all nondecreasing $f: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ Borel-measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

It is well-known that any nondecreasing function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is Borel-measurable.

Can this property be generalized to nondecreasing functions defined on $\mathbb R^d$?

To be precise, let's fix the following definitions:

- A function $f: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ is said to be *Borel-measurable* if $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal B (\mathbb R^d)$ holds for all $B \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, where $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^k)$ denotes the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb R^k$.
- Given $x, x' \in \mathbb R^d$ write $x \le x'$ if $x_k \le x'_k$ holds for all $k = 1,\dots, d$.
- A function $f: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ is said to be *nondecreasing* if $\forall x, x' \in \mathbb R^d$, $x \le x'$ implies $f(x) \le f(x')$

**Question:** Is every nondecreasing function $f: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ Borel-measurable?

Comment: What do you mean by $x \le x'$ when these are $d$-uples?

Comment: @Crostul the comparison is meant coordinate-wise: 

Given $x, x' \in \mathbb R^d$ write $x \le x'$ if $x_k \le x'_k$ holds for all $k = 1,\dots, d$

Comment: HINT: set $d=2$ and use induction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose a subset $N$ of $\mathbb{R}$ which is not Borel-measurable and define $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ by

$$ f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
3, & x + y > 0; \\
2, & x + y = 0 \text{ and } x \in N; \\
1, & x + y = 0 \text{ and } x \notin N; \\
0, & x + y < 0.
\end{cases} $$

Then it is not hard to check that $f$ is non-decreasing. On the other hand, $f^{-1}(\{2\})$ is not Borel-measurable.

Intuitively speaking, a non-decreasing function in dimension $\geq 2$ can have uncountable number of jumps, which allows to encode certain non-measurability into the set of jumps.